# Как отсортировать значения при использовании WM_CONCAT?

Tags: sql, oracle

В наличии БД Oracle 10 версии(`list_agg` еще нет).
Надо написать запрос в котором будут значения будут группироваться по ключу, а вторая колонка склеится в строку. При этом склеенная строка будет отсортирована по алфовиту.
Пробую писать так:

```
select CM.Class,
   to_char( replace( wm_concat( CM.Method ),',','' ) ) as MethodsList
  from
  (
    select distinct
           t1.Child  as Class, 
           t2.Symbol as Method
      from Table1 t1
     inner join Table2 t2
        on t1.id=t2.id       
     order by t1.Child, t2.Symbol
  ) CM
  group by CM.Class
  order by CM.Class;
```

Однако после склеивания в колонке `MethodsList` значения получаются не отсортированными.
Мои безуспешные попытки решить проблему:

1) Добавил сортировку в подзапрос(`CM`), рассчитывая, что заранее отсортированные данные склеятся в нужном порядке.

2) Кажется, что оптимизатор игнорирует мой `order by`, пробовал добавлять в подзапрос `rownum`, рассчитывая, что у оптимизатора не останется выбора, кроме как отсортировать

3) Так же пробовал использовать XML шаблоны для склейки, значения точно так же не сортируются.

4) Написал используя `conenct by`. Сортирует, но слишком медленно.

5) Сейчас в стадии попыток написать свою собственную функцию с сортировкой

Подскажите, что еще можно попробовать, чтобы значения при склейке сортировались?

PS
  Я знаю, что WM_CONCAT недокументированная функция и ведет себя иногда странно и загадочно. Код пока тестовый и используется для построения прототипа. В промышленное решение пойдет 11 Oracle и `list_agg`

Comment: Если эта не работает , можно написать свою функцию которая будет на вход принимать значение ключа  а на выход выдавать строку, с помощью цикла for например, и эту функцию подставить в select.

Comment: Я  пытаюсь сейчас разобраться, как добавить сортировку в свою агрегатную функцию. Если Вы где то видели пример, дайте ссылочку)

Comment: Если работать будет на 11, то зачем сейчас тратить время на изобретение собственной listagg. Оставили бы неотсортированным или сразу тест на 11 перенесли. Я сомневаюсь, что есть быстрый метод. И вам видимо надо делать не агрегатную функцию, а простую, получающую на вход CM.Class и возвращающую строку для него

Comment: Время можно тратить как минимум потому, что это интересно. 11 нет в наличии, просто взять и поставить не позволяют корпоративные политики безопасности. А вот про функцию спасибо, для тестов она вполне подойдет. Немножко обидно, что сам не додумался. Готов принять как ответ, если оформите)

Comment: А это же не я предложил, @heff первым же комментарием сказал то же самое, просто я перефразировал :) Вот еще нашел http://www.sql.ru/forum/166325/rezultat-select-a-v-odnu-stroku  sysxml_agg там же пишут что вроде как нет 100% гарантии сортировки. Зато там еще кто то функцию с курсором написал ...

Comment: оформил как ответ)

Comment: И кстати еще вариант есть, но влом сейчас эксперименировать. Я в свое время делал пакетную кеширующую функцию, которая получала по id название и запоминала до 10 штук в коллекции в пакете. И при следующем обращении возвращать умела из коллекции, это сильно ускоряло всякие формы. Так вот, можно сделать функцию, которая будет запоминать в пакетной коллекции поступившние на вход значения (в порядке поступления) и вторую функцию, которая вернет собранное в строку значение. и потом case на последних строках группы (определять по row_number() over ) вызывать вторую

Comment: а потом кому нибудь достанется разбирать этот код)) представляю лицо этого человека когда он поймет что всего лишь строчку надо было сканкатеновать ,если конечно поймет))

Comment: @mike с XML пробовал, результат тот же самый. @heff Извиняюсь, не понял Ваш комментарий сразу. Надеюсь никому не придется разбирать, в пром уйдет `listagg`. Сейчас только прототип)

Comment: мой последний комментарий относился к комментарию майка про кеширование.

Comment: @lDrakonl тогда не заметил этого вопроса, но позже отвечал на похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704280/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-oracle-xml/704703#704703) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352068/how-to-fetch-different-records-in-same-row-in-sql/44352791#44352791) без учёта 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если подходящей функции нет то, можно написать свою функцию которая будет на вход принимать значение ключа а на выход выдавать строку, с помощью цикла for например, и вызов этой функции подставить в select.