# Обратное преобразование спецсимволов для oracle xml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Необходимо в запросе выполнить конкатенацию строк в группировке. Так как для Oracle 10g стандартной функции нет, реализовал через XML:

```
select id, cast(sys_xmlagg(xmlelement(col, '<' || name || '>')).extract('/ROWSET/COL/text()') as varchar2(4000))
from table 
group by id;
```

Проблема в том что на выходе получаю:

```
1  &lt;name1&gt;
2  &lt;name2&gt;
3  &lt;name1&gt;&lt;name2&gt;
4  &lt;name1&gt;&lt;name2&gt;&lt;name3&gt;
```

А нужно:

```
1  <name1>
2  <name2>
3  <name1><name2>
4  <name1><name2><name3>
```

Возможно есть стандартная функция обратного преобразования спецсимволов по лучше чем replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По моему мнению, для приведённого примера, `replace` или `regexp_replace` это лучший выбор.

Другая альтернатива, использовать другие средства, также доступные в 10g, не "злоупотребляя" `XmlType`. Например, использовать аналитические функции:

```
with data as (
    select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all 
    select 2 id, 'name1' name from dual union all 
    select 2 id, 'name2' name from dual union all 
    select 3 id, 'name1' name from dual union all 
    select 3 id, 'name2' name from dual union all 
    select 3 id, 'name3' name from dual)
select id, 
    max(sys_connect_by_path(name||'>', '<')) keep (dense_rank last order by this) names 
from (
    select id, name,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by name) this,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by name)-1 prev
    from data
    )
group by id
connect by prior this = prev and prior id = id start with this = 1 
; 

1 <name1>                                 
2 <name1><name2>                          
3 <name1><name2><name3>
```

Если всё таки предпочтительна агрегатная функция, то в 10g есть не документированная функция `wmsys.WM_CONCAT`. Так как, она неофициальная и не поддерживается, то не желательно её использование в продуктивной среде.
 Можно написать свою функцию по её подобию. Пример кода, помимо прочего, есть на [спроси Тома](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402). Такое решение будет возможно даже более изящным, чем с `sys_connect_by_path`:

```
create or replace type myAggType as object (
    values_  varchar2(32767),
    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx in out myAggType) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out myAggType, value in varchar2) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self myAggType, returnValue out varchar2, flags number) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out myAggType, ctx2 in myAggType) return number
);
/

create or replace type body myAggType IS
    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx in out myAggType) return number is
    begin
        ctx := myAggType (null); 
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out myAggType, value varchar2) return number is
    begin
        self.values_ := self.values_||'<'||value||'>';
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self myAggType, returnValue out varchar2, flags number) return number is
    begin
        returnValue := self.values_;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out myAggType, ctx2 myAggType) return number is
    begin
        self.values_ := self.values_||ctx2.values_;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;
end;
/

create or replace function myAgg (input varchar2) return varchar2 parallel_enable aggregate using myAggType;
/

with data as (<см. выше>) select id, myAgg(name) names from data group by id
;    

  ID NAMES                                  
---- ----------------------------------------
   1 <name1>                                 
   2 <name1><name2>                          
   3 <name1><name3><name2>
```

А также, если данных не много, можно создать специфическую функцию, которая получит запрос как `sys_refcursor` или данные с `collect` и выдаст как возврат конкантинацию данных в виде, удовлетворяющем конкретным техническим требованиям.

**Предыдущий ответ** (не подходит, т.к работает только при возврате одного узла)

В вашем примере `extract` возвращает `XMLType`. Поэтому `cast()` конвертирует `clob`, получаемый из `XMLType`, в `varchar2`, но он никакого представления не имеет о его XML содержимом, т.е shit-in/shit-out.

Попробуйте с помощью `extractValue()` вернуть скалярные значения узлов. Его тип возврата по умолчанию - `varchar2(4000)`. Ну где то так:

```
select 
    extractValue(xml, '/col[1]/text()') val1,
    extractValue(xml, '/col[2]/text()') val2 
 from (   
     select xmlagg(xmlel) xml from (
        select xmlelement("col", '<' || 'name1' || '>') xmlel from dual union all
        select xmlelement("col", '<' || 'name2' || '>') xmlel from dual   
));
```

Вывод:

```
<name1>
<name2>
```

Comment: К сожалению EXTRACTVALUE может возвращать значение только одного узла, сложность как раз и заключается в том, что в моем случае узлов COL может быть несколько.

Comment: А, теперь понял вашу задачу. Тогда возможно правильней отказаться от xmlagg вообще и написать свою функцию по подобию listagg().